# Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page in Apple developer site is redirecting to Account page

Tags: ios

I'm trying to access the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page in Apple Developer site, however, there's no such hyperlink visible once I login.

When I enter the address as https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/development it is redirecting to the Account page i.e. https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome

Can someone pls guide what steps do I need to take? I've tried clearing the browser cache & history, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of exploration, found out that the options aren't visible unless one has a ***paid developer account***

Further details are available here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47466